# FFMPEG, Blur an area of a video using Image Select Areas Plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, video, ffmpeg

I am building an online video editor. I need to allow the users to blur an area of movies. This must be done graphically, I mean user should be able to select an area of a video, using an screenshot, then the selected area must be blurred. Some thing like this

[image]

Is there anyway to map this selected area dimension and its distance from borders to the real values that must be applied to the video?

I mean four numbers, `width, length, top, left` will be provided using this plug in and I need to use these numbers to blur an area of videos.

I take an screenshot of video. In order to keep the aspect ratio, I will fix the width to `800px` and let the height to be scaled up/down. It is clear that the `width, length, top, left` of the selected area of the screenshot is a factor of the `width, length, top, left` of the area that must be blurred in video. but I don't know how to get this factor. Besides that I don't know how to get the video resolution.

Thanks in advance.

---

## Update

This is my PHP code that gets the selected area  dimensions and offsets

```
$iLeft = $_POST['left'];
$iTop = $_POST['top'];
$iWidth = $_POST['width'];
$iHeight = $_POST['height'];
exec('ffmpeg -i '.$url.' -filter_complex "[0:v]scale=iw*sar:ih,setsar=1,split[bg][bb];[bb]crop='.$iWidth.'*iw/800:iw*'.$iHeight.'/800:'.$iWidth.'*iw/800:'.$iHeight.'*iw/800,boxblur=10[b0];[bg][b0]overlay='.$iLeft.'*W/800:'.$iTop.'*W/800"" '.$name.' > block.txt 2>&1');
```

`$iLeft, $iTop, $iWidth, $iHeight` are the left, top, width and height of the selected area via the image plugin.

It blurs many selected areas very well, but areas like this

[image]

The Image `Left, Top, Width, Height` is `257,  39.26666259765625,  10,  391`

don't get blurred. Also a video with Dimension `207x207` didn't get blurred as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Running

```
ffprobe in.mp4 -loglevel quiet -select_streams v -show_entries stream=width,height,sample_aspect_ratio -of compact=p=0:nk=1
```

will produce an output that looks like this:

```
1280|720|1:1
```

The first entry is the video width, then the height, and finally the pixel or sample aspect ratio, shown as num:den so it's num/den. That's your video resolution.

With that info, the factor is `video-width*sar/800`. This assumes that you'll be scaling all anamorphic videos to square pixels using the `scale` and `setsar` filters, and that the 800px screenshot is undistorted as well. If you're using FFmpeg to scale screenshot, it's `scale=800:ih*800/iw/sar`

So FFmpeg value for area width is `screenshot area width * video-width*sar/800`.

and for FFmpeg Y co-ordinate is `screenshot top * video-width*sar/800`, and so on.

---

Assuming the code in the comment is for the screenshot, for the full-sized movie, it would be

```
"[0:v]scale=iw*sar:ih,setsar=1,split[bg][bb];[bb]crop=50*iw/800:50*iw/800:20*iw/800:10*iw/800,boxblur='min(min(cw/2\,ch/2)\,10)'[b0];
 [bg][b0]overlay=20*W/800:10*W/800"
```

I've scaled the movie to make sure we're always dealing with a square-pixel video.

Comment: Thank you very much. This is the code I use to blur a rectangle , `ffmpeg -i 1_test.mov -filter_complex "[0:v]crop=50:50:20:10,boxblur=10[b0];[0:v][b0]overlay=10:10" intro-blur.mov`. I guess I can simplify the filters, right? the `50:50` is the blur area width/height and `overlay=10:10` is its top/left. How can this code be simplified by replacing the new values you mentioned above? In fact I need to rewrite this code

Comment: See edit. Note that `top` is the Y and `left` is the X, so it's `overlay=left:top` and also `crop=width:length:left:top` in terms of your original names.

Comment: Where did you use the variables of the Image Select Plugin in the `[0:v]scale=iw*sar:ih,setsar=1,split[bg][bb];[bb]crop=50*iw/800:50*iw/800:20*iw/800:10*iw/800,boxblur=10[b0];
 [bg][b0]overlay=20*W/800:10*W/800`?

Comment: But this code works perfectly, better than the previous one. thanks again

Comment: One more problem. I got the code for blurring from `http://superuser.com/questions/901099/ffmpeg-apply-blur-over-face`. He says **The x and y offset numbers in overlay  must match the crop offsets.** My code for blurring using the above variables doesn't convert some videos. Is there any simpler code for blurring?

Comment: The width of the original video.

Comment: I updated the question. There is a case that it doesn't blur at all. I would be appreciated if you take a look at it.

Comment: In the new image, the whole image is blurred except for the thin vertical strip. Isn't that what you want?

Comment: No, FFMPEG stopped blurring. It didn't blur at all. a file with `0 KB` size created

Comment: In the image you posted, I can see the Discovery logo blurred. Did you mean to post another image?

Comment: The image is Image Select Area Plugin where the rectangle selects the area. It is not the output of video. It only selects the area

Comment: The selected area `Left, Top, Width, Height` is `257,  39.26666259765625,  10,  391`

Comment: The filter  is `[0:v]scale=iw*sar:ih,setsar=1,split[bg][bb];[bb]crop='.$iWidth.'*iw/800:iw*'.$iHeight.'/800:'.$iWidth.'*iw/800:'.$iHeight.'*iw/800,boxblur=10[b0];[bg][b0]overlay='.$iLeft.'*W/800:'.$iTop.'*W/800"`

Comment: Your width is 10 and since chroma is half-width, boxblur can be max 2.5

Comment: Change boxblur to 2.5.

Comment: I tried this and it works very perfectly. But for a video with `207x207` resolution it didn't work :(

Comment: Thank you veryyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyy much. It is working now. I tried for every example that it didn't work, but it is working now. thanks again